# Android emulator with Hyper V

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, hyper-v

According to this [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/) it should be possible now to run an Android emulator with activated Hyper-V on Windows (so we should be able to run Docker beside an Android emulator). I already installed the Windows 10 April 2018 update, downloaded the latest Android emulator (v 27.2.9) and add the WindowsHypervisorPlatform flag.

I can start the emulatour within the powershell console, I get no warning about activated Hyper-V and I can see as output "Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational". So I guess the flag is working correctly.

But for some reason, Android is not booting. The emulator screen stays black.

I tried different Android System Images, but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, i would suggest you should update the Android Studio to latest version (stable), i.e. 3.1.2 and also update the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm able to get it to work is if I start Android Device Manager **through Visual Studio**.

From menu `Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager`

I had to fiddle around a little with android SDK and reinstall tools and images through the SDK manager in Visual Studio as well, but it works surprisingly well!

Answer (score 0):

Tested on **Visual Studio 15.8.1** (Aug 17 release)

To resolve this issue:

> Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager

Right click the affected emulator, Factory Rest.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

open `cmd(Command Prompt)` in this path C:/users/your_session_name/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools and type: `emulator -list-avds` , this command will print the created avds(let's say emulators) for example : `Pixel_2_API_25`

then type: `emulator @Pixel_2_API_25  -writable-system -no-audio -gpu guest`

this will force to reboot the android emulator